# How to read a text file contents word by word in an array in php

Tags: php

I have a text file with 8-10 words in each line with sequence no.and spaces.
e.g 1)word 2)word 3)word 4)word .........
and i want to read it in an one dimensional array only words not sequence no.

Comment: show a clearer sample of your file.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your file looks like this:

```
1)First 2)Second 3)Third 4)Forth
5)Fifth 6)Sixth ..
```

Using this function you can extract the word only:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+\)(\w+)/', $file_data, $matches);
```

Now `$matches[1]` will contain:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => First
        [1] => Second
        [2] => Third
        [3] => Fourth
        [4] => Fifth
        [6] => Sixth
    )
```

Comment: Another possible regex would be #(?<=\b)([A-Za-z]+)(?=\b)#. It matches all words regardless of any surrounding numbers, brackets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you have each word on new line then you get lines first:

```
$contents = file_get_contents ($path_to_file);
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);
if (!empty($lines)) {
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        // Then you get rid of sequence
        $word_line = preg_replace("/^([0-9]\))/Ui", "", $x);
        $words = explode(" ", $word_line); 
    }
}
```

(assuming sequence starts with "x)" )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming file contents is just like what duckyflip illustrated, another possible way

```
$content = file_get_contents("file");
$s = preg_split("/\d+\)|\n/",$content);
print_r(array_filter($s));
```

output

```
$ php test.php
Array
(
    [1] => First
    [2] => Second
    [3] => Third
    [4] => Forth
    [6] => Fifth
    [7] => Sixth
)
```